# UnicodeEncodeError when using search_fields in Django admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm very new at Django and have UnicodeEncodeError when using search_fields in admin with cyrillic symbols. Search with ascii symbols works properly. What should I look for?

```
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/persons/person/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

models.py

```
class Person(GenericModel, DatePeriodMixin):
    last_name = models.CharField(_(u'фамилия'), max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(_(u'имя'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    patronymic = models.CharField(_(u'отчество'), max_length=255, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('персоналия')
        verbose_name_plural = _('персоналии')
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'patronymic']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{} {} {}'.format(
            self.last_name,
            self.first_name,
            self.patronymic).rstrip()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('persons:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'patronymic')
    search_fields = ['last_name']
    list_filter = ('profession')
    filter_horizontal = ('organizations', 'profession')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.editor = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: If you could also provide the code that is throwing the exception - /admin/persons/person/ - it will offer a better chance of somebody being able to show you where the error lies.

Comment: @PTD updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it by adding this to admin.py:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

(found it here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2912)

Not sure what it was, but now works for me. Now going to study about codecs in python.